# Null pointer on service in REST using jersey and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, struts2

I'm creating application using struts2, hibernate, spring and REST using jersey. All part of my application is working but in my REST i got null pointer

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

cause mère

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.project.caritas.rest.MedicamentJsonRest.getMedicament(MedicamentJsonRest.java:35)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

My spring config looks like this

```
<bean id="medicamentDAO" class="com.project.caritas.dao.impl.MedicamentDAOImpl" parent="abstractDAO" />

<bean id="medicamentService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" parent="abstractService">
    <property name="target">
        <bean id="medicamentServiceImpl" class="com.project.caritas.service.impl.MedicamentServiceImpl">
            <property name="medicamentDAO" ref="medicamentDAO" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="medicamentJsonRest" class="com.project.caritas.rest.MedicamentJsonRest">
    <property name="medicamentService" ref="medicamentService" />
</bean>
```

And my REST Class

```
@Path("/json/medicaments")
public class MedicamentJsonRest {

private MedicamentService medicamentService;

@GET
@Path("/find")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Medicaments getMedicament(){
    Medicaments m = new Medicaments();

    try {
        m = medicamentService.find(1);
    } catch (NonExistentEntityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MedicamentJsonRest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return m;
}

/**
 * @return the medicamentService
 */
public MedicamentService getMedicamentService() {
    return medicamentService;
}

/**
 * @param medicamentService the medicamentService to set
 */
public void setMedicamentService(MedicamentService medicamentService) {
    this.medicamentService = medicamentService;
}
}
```

Web.xml jersey configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.project.caritas.rest.RestApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My question is why medicamentService have null value it is not handled by Spring? 
Thanks for you're answer and sorry for my bad english

Comment: The service is not @Autowired

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: please post complete stack trace.

Comment: why <bean  .. parent="abstractService"> in TxnProxyFactoryBean configuration?

Comment: abstractService set the transactionManager and transactionAttributes property.

Comment: what is your web.xml and jersey servlet configurations?

Comment: I add web.xml in the post

Comment: does your com.project.caritas.rest.RestApplication getClasses() returns your 'MedicamentJsonRest' ?
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet

Comment: Yes. I've created 2 REST one who just said hello word, it works. and another using service with this i got nullpointer. i think that it is dependency injection issue.

Comment: Finally i solve this issue by adding <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.caritas.rest.*" /> to my spring configuration

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem might be that you define your Rest Controller as a Bean. Normally if you use Spring and Jersey you dont define your rest controllers as beans, because Jersey will initiate those classes for you. Just use the RestController annoation like this so Autowire and all the annotation based things still work:

```
@Path("/json/medicaments")
@RestController
public class MedicamentJsonRest {
...
}
```

Edit:

Also in servlet you should use:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>my.package.name</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: RestController is used by springMVC but i'm just using spring for Depedency Injection. All my controller is written with struts2. I've tried to add RestController annotation but the library is not found so i can't compile

Comment: I add SpringMVC in my maven dependecy and and RestController annotation but still got the same error

Comment: Seemy updated answer. You might need to pass the init-param in your servlet as well.

Comment: Nothing change still got the same error. i think it's spring issue